# Creating a show hide function on window load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a script which someone assisted me with on stackoverflow. It works perfectly, however it does not work with my amchart in IE8-10 (I have logged this issue with amcharts too because the issue appears to be with the chart).

I would like to troubleshoot further myself in the meantime with jQuery script. I am still learning jQuery and need some guidance in converting the following javascript code to a jQuery show() hide() script.

I have tried it in it basic form:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$("div").hide();
};
```

It works in all other browser except IE 8-10 when you toggle the form the chart does not appear. Below please see exerpts of two scripts that work but in IE 8-10.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function chart1() {
var show = ['chartdiv1', 'unit-price'];
for ( var i = 0; i < show.length; ++i ) 
document.getElementById(show[i]).style.display = "block";
var hide = ['chartdiv2', 'unit-price-value','chartdiv3', 'unit-price-rand'];
for ( var i = 0; i < hide.length; ++i ) 
     document.getElementById(hide[i]).style.display = "none";
};

   </script>

    <script>
    function chart1() {
    document.getElementById("chartdiv1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("unit-price").style.display = "block";
    };
    function chart2() {
    document.getElementById("chartdiv2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("unit-price-value").style.display = "none";
    };
    function chart3() {
    document.getElementById("chartdiv3").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("unit-price-rand").style.display = "none";
    };
    </script>


</head>
<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF; margin: 10px;" onLoad="chart1()"> or onload"chart1(), chart2(),.............
```

Comment: use `$("div").toggle()`

Comment: you write $("div">.hide(); is it ok ?. i think it is $("div").hide(); m i right ?

Comment: sorry about that, you are correct in saying $("div") I typed it out incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a syntax error in your code.

Shouldn't the function be like this? :

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("div").hide(); //and not $("div">.hide();
}); // added the closing bracket of load function
```

Comment: closing should be `});` not `}`.

Comment: @Jai: Thanks. didnt see that :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $("div").hide();
   $("#chartdiv1, #unit-price").show();
});
```

---

On window load you just hide all the divs but it is still better to hide it with css. then just show the div with specific ids you want to show.